# Is it possible to use Minecraft bukkit AND forge at the same time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a minecraft server which I can change the JARs on. Currently I am using v 1.2.5 of Minecraft_server jar with Minecraft Forge installed to allow the use of the Buildcraft mods.
On my previous server I just had bukkit installed, this allowed me to install mods like worldedit, but not buildcraft.

I really need a mod that will allow world editing and creative building, but I don't want to lose buildcraft. Is it possible to have bukkit and forge running at the same time? How would I start? Seems you can only download bukkit as a JAR.

Alternatively, a mod which is/like worldedit that would be compatible - although I would rather like to get Bukkit loaded so I can use things like "Essentials"

Comment: Forgot to add as a addendum to the bounty, but the more comprehensive answer outside the scope of this answer (means historical to now), the better.

Comment: The last part of the question apparently asks for mod recommendations, in that case it will be off-topic now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://mcportcentral.co.za/wiki/index.php?title=Ports_for_1.2.5) is a version of buildcraft that has been ported to Craftbukkit format. It will work as a plugin.

Comment: Ah, brilliant. Last time I tried to check there for ports, it was always empty! I'll check it out :)

Answer (score 3):

[MCPC](http://www.mcportcentral.co.za/) is a version of Bukkit that runs forge mods that have been ported across to Bukkit. It is more commonly seen in the Techic pack (Tekkit).

Answer (score 1):

#### There is currently no way to download it due to the DMCA takedowns of Bukkit.

However, here are the latest links:

---

The download page is still [here](http://cauldron.minecraftforge.net/), but does not have any downloads as they are removed due to the DMCA takedown.

Am update posted on the [2nd of December](http://cauldron.minecraftforge.net/threads/downloads-removed-working-on-sponge-1-8.780/), stating that the project will be reopened, using a [completely new fork of the Bukkit](https://www.spongepowered.org/) project (thus using mainly original code, and not those of which infringed the [copyright of Wesley Wolfe](http://dl.bukkit.org/dmca/notification.txt).

For now, a backup download page have been created at http://minecraft.maeyanie.com/cauldron/, which may not avaliable in the future. (At the time of this post, it is.)

If you have found any other download source, be sure to make sure that its checksum matches to which was provided by the developers to avoid downloading one with viruses etc. in it.
http://pastebin.com/vVCUmtYD

```
599415ad54b4a2417d90a1977187ca3b  maven\net\minecraftforge\cauldron\1.7.10-1.1207.01.198\cauldron-1.7.10-1.1207.01.198-server.jar
f8d87f12bd89c7643a7ce9192bdc253e  maven\net\minecraftforge\cauldron\1.7.10-1.1207.01.198\cauldron-1.7.10-1.1207.01.198-installer.jar
e1df3797ba1aed4c19220902df356fcb  maven\net\minecraftforge\cauldron\1.7.10-1.1207.01.198\cauldron-1.7.10-1.1207.01.198-installer-win.exe
3c994c0a9ac5bc785855ea7d7d120ca2  maven\net\minecraftforge\cauldron\1.7.10-1.1207.01.198\cauldron-1.7.10-1.1207.01.198-changelog.txt
32a8d3aa64bcb00bfc98a3c44aa17442  maven\net\minecraftforge\cauldron\1.7.2-1.1147.04.196\cauldron-1.7.2-1.1147.04.196-changelog.txt
a40494cf175cbd873fa618f0f4a718d2  maven\net\minecraftforge\cauldron\1.7.2-1.1147.04.196\cauldron-1.7.2-1.1147.04.196-installer-win.exe
095eab1fdda445ae4f6a2a591b58df8c  maven\net\minecraftforge\cauldron\1.7.2-1.1147.04.196\cauldron-1.7.2-1.1147.04.196-installer.jar
111faa563e6483e35e6121ce7971ae08  maven\net\minecraftforge\cauldron\1.7.2-1.1147.04.196\cauldron-1.7.2-1.1147.04.196-server.jar
6e58f8d86901f9787c7100e2bfaf7627  maven\net\minecraftforge\cauldron\1.6.4-1.965.21.204\cauldron-1.6.4-1.965.21.204-installer.jar
3b51f4f1f2a5893064f7d8a51028e295  maven\net\minecraftforge\cauldron\1.6.4-1.965.21.204\cauldron-1.6.4-1.965.21.204-installer-win.exe
73f80b7518d6c0cabaa026696dcc7d15  maven\net\minecraftforge\cauldron\1.6.4-1.965.21.204\cauldron-1.6.4-1.965.21.204-server.jar
9ade289ecf2c2ff4e231985526260ef3  maven\net\minecraftforge\cauldron\1.6.4-1.965.21.204\cauldron-1.6.4-1.965.21.204-changelog.txt
ca45b3cf110759491e41a141b8df3304  maven\net\minecraftforge\cauldron\1.6.4-1.965.21.45\cauldron-1.6.4-1.965.21.45-changelog.txt
dec2723f918878b2cde26d1634d5fb94  maven\net\minecraftforge\cauldron\1.6.4-1.965.21.45\cauldron-1.6.4-1.965.21.45-installer-win.exe
48341a796f7d9aec6d781ca3cafa7ff2  maven\net\minecraftforge\cauldron\1.6.4-1.965.21.45\cauldron-1.6.4-1.965.21.45-installer.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

There's [BukkitForge](https://github.com/keepcalm/BukkitForge), a Forge mod which can run Bukkit plugins. It works on any Forge server.

There's also [Cauldron](http://ci.md-5.net/job/Cauldron/) for Minecraft 1.7, [MCPC-Plus](http://ci.md-5.net/job/MCPC-Plus-Dev/) for 1.6, and [MCPC-Plus-Legacy](http://ci.md-5.net/job/MCPC-Plus-Legacy/) for 1.5, all of which are Bukkit servers with Forge built into them.

I recommend using Cauldron or MCPC-Plus, as BukkitForge's support for plugins is not natively built in. Be warned that Multiverse plugins do not always play nice with MCPC-Plus.